# Install windows 7 on a VM running in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm running windows 7 on my PC and I need to set a VM (i.e. using virtualbox) running windows 7 (no other OS). How can i do it? I can't use my OEM licence product key to install windows 7 in the VM I guess. I want neither to buy another licence, nor to use a crack as I already have a valid licence and I need it only for testing purposes. Any hints?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. We accept questions asking for a specific recommendations for software to do a specific task, not asking how to use a piece of software, or deciphering licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Modern.IE](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/), where Microsoft provides free VMs (with options for Virtualbox, VmWare and other hosts depending on the host OS) with different pre-installed versions of Windows and Internet Explorer.

It is mainly aimed at web developers who want to test their sites in different versions of IE, but as far as I have tested the VMs run full Windows installations (for Windows 7 specifically, this means a Windows 7 Enterpise Edition installation).

The trial period for a VM is 90 days (meaning you should activate it with a valid license after that period) but it can be worked around e.g. with VirtualBox snapshots or simply saving the downloaded vm and reimporting it if it's an option.

Comment: I'll give it a try.. but I have a question: what is inside this VMs? A full windows 7? I don't need IE, as I have to test desktop applications I made in .NET..

Comment: Edited to better phrase it, but as far as I know yes, it's a full Windows 7 (Enterprise Edition) installation

Answer (score 1):

I think OEM license will allow you to install Windows several times (5 I believe) -- this is allowed in case you need to re-install your system a few times.

Comment: The problem now is to find a .iso of windows 7... with OEM licence you are not allowed to do it from microsoft website, I should ask to my manufacturer for a recovery dvd, but they won't give me for free.. :(